# THREE.JS + Delaunator.JS Keeping faces indexing

Tags: indexing, three.js, mapbox, delaunay, face

Probably this question is for Mapbox team and Delaunator.JS developers, but I hope that somebody could help me here.

I have a pseudo quadtree geometry (THREE.BufferGeometry) set by series of points having seven partitions with their individual draw call (geometry.addGroup() method) and material.

[image]

```
//pseudo quadtree
var points = [], indices = [], quad_uvs = [], groups = [], materials = [];
getSegmentSubpoints(0, new THREE.Vector3(-1024, 0, -1024), 1024, 1024, 4);
getSegmentSubpoints(1, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1024), 1024, 1024, 4);
getSegmentSubpoints(2, new THREE.Vector3(-1024, 0, 0), 1024, 1024, 4);
 
getSegmentSubpoints(3, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(4, new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, 0), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(5, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 512), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(6, new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, 512), 512, 512, 8);
  
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
    
geometry.setIndex(indices);
    
geometry.setAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(quad_uvs), 2 ) );
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
var colors = [new THREE.Color(0xe6194b), new THREE.Color(0x3cb44b), new THREE.Color(0xffe119), new THREE.Color(0x4363d8), new THREE.Color(0xf58231), new THREE.Color(0x911eb4), new THREE.Color(0x46f0f0) ]
groups.forEach(function(g_, i_){ geometry.addGroup(g_.start, g_.end, g_.id); });
    
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
plane.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, 0);
plane.position.set(-1152, 0, 0);
scene.add(plane);

function getSegmentSubpoints(id_, lt_, w_, h_, level_){
    
    var subpoints = [];
    var subindices = [];
    var subquad = [];
    var lastIndex = points.length;
    var lastIndex2 = indices.length;
    
    var step = {x: w_ / level_, z: h_ / level_ };
    var stepT = {x: 1.0 / level_, z: 1.0 / level_ };
    
    for(var z = 0; z <= level_; z++){
        for(var x = 0; x <= level_; x++){
            
            var dx = lt_.x + step.x * x;
            var dz = lt_.z + step.z * z;
            var dy = noise.simplex2(dx / 512.0, dz / 512.0) * 32.0;
            
            subquad.push(...[stepT.x * x, stepT.z * z]);
            subpoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(dx, dy, dz));
        }
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < subpoints.length - level_ - 2; i++) {
        
        if(i % (level_ + 1) != (level_)){
        subindices.push(lastIndex + i, lastIndex + i + 1, lastIndex + i + level_ + 2, lastIndex + i + level_ + 2, lastIndex + i + level_ + 1, lastIndex + i);
        }
        
    }
   
    points.push(...subpoints);
    indices.push(...subindices);
    quad_uvs.push(...subquad);
    groups.push({id: id_, start: lastIndex2, end: subindices.length});
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true, map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("textures/" + id_ + ".jpg")}));
    
}
```

Everything is fine, but for my project I have to process the current geometry through Delaunator.JS and it seems that the output has different triangles/faces indexing starting from the center.

**There is dynamic colors for each segment to visualize indexing. Eventually, it has to be the same as previous one with seven materials and individual draw calls.**

[image]

```
//delaunay
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
var indexDelaunay = Delaunator.from(points.map(v => { return [v.x, v.z]; }) );
var meshIndex = [];
for (let i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i++){ meshIndex.push(indexDelaunay.triangles[i]); }

geometry.setIndex(meshIndex);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
count = 0;
    
for(var i = 0; i < meshIndex.length; i += 6){
    
    geometry.addGroup(i, 6, i / 6);
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true, color: new THREE.Color("hsl(" + (360 / 316 * count) + ",80%, 80%)")}))
    count++;
    
}
      
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
plane.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, 0)
plane.position.set(1152, 0, 0); 
scene.add(plane);
```

So is there a way to re-index faces back so I could get the same result?
Yes, I could go through each Delaunator.triangles check its position/area for if it fits the certain partition, but it's not an elegant and fast solution. I bet it's possible to tweak Delaunator.JS code for right indexing on the fly.

The snippet is attached as well.

```js
//https://hofk.de/main/discourse.threejs/2018/Triangulation/Triangulation.html
////by Mapbox https://github.com/mapbox/delaunator

(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.Delaunator = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

    var EPSILON = Math.pow(2, -52);

    var Delaunator = function Delaunator(coords) {
        var this$1 = this;

        var n = coords.length >> 1;
        if (n > 0 && typeof coords[0] !== 'number') { throw new Error('Expected coords to contain numbers.'); }

        this.coords = coords;

        var maxTriangles = 2 * n - 5;
        var triangles = this.triangles = new Uint32Array(maxTriangles * 3);
        var halfedges = this.halfedges = new Int32Array(maxTriangles * 3);

        this._hashSize = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
        var hullPrev = this.hullPrev = new Uint32Array(n);
        var hullNext = this.hullNext = new Uint32Array(n);
        var hullTri = this.hullTri = new Uint32Array(n);
        var hullHash = new Int32Array(this._hashSize).fill(-1);
        
        var ids = new Uint32Array(n);
        var minX = Infinity;
        var minY = Infinity;
        var maxX = -Infinity;
        var maxY = -Infinity;

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var x = coords[2 * i];
            var y = coords[2 * i + 1];
            if (x < minX) { minX = x; }
            if (y < minY) { minY = y; }
            if (x > maxX) { maxX = x; }
            if (y > maxY) { maxY = y; }
            ids[i] = i;
        }
        var cx = (minX + maxX) / 2;
        var cy = (minY + maxY) / 2;

        var minDist = Infinity;
        var i0, i1, i2;

        for (var i$1 = 0; i$1 < n; i$1++) {
            var d = dist(cx, cy, coords[2 * i$1], coords[2 * i$1 + 1]);
            if (d < minDist) {
                i0 = i$1;
                minDist = d;
            }
        }
        var i0x = coords[2 * i0];
        var i0y = coords[2 * i0 + 1];

        minDist = Infinity;

        for (var i$2 = 0; i$2 < n; i$2++) {
            if (i$2 === i0) { continue; }
            var d$1 = dist(i0x, i0y, coords[2 * i$2], coords[2 * i$2 + 1]);
            if (d$1 < minDist && d$1 > 0) {
                i1 = i$2;
                minDist = d$1;
            }
        }
        var i1x = coords[2 * i1];
        var i1y = coords[2 * i1 + 1];

        var minRadius = Infinity;

        for (var i$3 = 0; i$3 < n; i$3++) {
            if (i$3 === i0 || i$3 === i1) { continue; }
            var r = circumradius(i0x, i0y, i1x, i1y, coords[2 * i$3], coords[2 * i$3 + 1]);
            if (r < minRadius) {
                i2 = i$3;
                minRadius = r;
            }
        }
        var i2x = coords[2 * i2];
        var i2y = coords[2 * i2 + 1];

        if (minRadius === Infinity) {
            throw new Error('No Delaunay triangulation exists for this input.');
        }

        if (orient(i0x, i0y, i1x, i1y, i2x, i2y)) {
            var i$4 = i1;
            var x$1 = i1x;
            var y$1 = i1y;
            i1 = i2;
            i1x = i2x;
            i1y = i2y;
            i2 = i$4;
            i2x = x$1;
            i2y = y$1;
        }

        var center = circumcenter(i0x, i0y, i1x, i1y, i2x, i2y);
        this._cx = center.x;
        this._cy = center.y;

        var dists = new Float64Array(n);
        for (var i$5 = 0; i$5 < n; i$5++) {
            dists[i$5] = dist(coords[2 * i$5], coords[2 * i$5 + 1], center.x, center.y);
        }

        quicksort(ids, dists, 0, n - 1);

        this.hullStart = i0;
        var hullSize = 3;

        hullNext[i0] = hullPrev[i2] = i1;
        hullNext[i1] = hullPrev[i0] = i2;
        hullNext[i2] = hullPrev[i1] = i0;

        hullTri[i0] = 0;
        hullTri[i1] = 1;
        hullTri[i2] = 2;

        hullHash[this._hashKey(i0x, i0y)] = i0;
        hullHash[this._hashKey(i1x, i1y)] = i1;
        hullHash[this._hashKey(i2x, i2y)] = i2;

        this.trianglesLen = 0;
        this._addTriangle(i0, i1, i2, -1, -1, -1);

        for (var k = 0, xp = (void 0), yp = (void 0); k < ids.length; k++) {
            var i$6 = ids[k];
            var x$2 = coords[2 * i$6];
            var y$2 = coords[2 * i$6 + 1];

            if (k > 0 && Math.abs(x$2 - xp) <= EPSILON && Math.abs(y$2 - yp) <= EPSILON) { continue; }
            xp = x$2;
            yp = y$2;

            if (i$6 === i0 || i$6 === i1 || i$6 === i2) { continue; }

            var start = 0;
            for (var j = 0, key = this._hashKey(x$2, y$2); j < this._hashSize; j++) {
                start = hullHash[(key + j) % this$1._hashSize];
                if (start !== -1 && start !== hullNext[start]) { break; }
            }

            start = hullPrev[start];
            var e = start, q = (void 0);
            while (q = hullNext[e], !orient(x$2, y$2, coords[2 * e], coords[2 * e + 1], coords[2 * q], coords[2 * q + 1])) {
                e = q;
                if (e === start) {
                    e = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (e === -1) { continue; }

            var t = this$1._addTriangle(e, i$6, hullNext[e], -1, -1, hullTri[e]);

            hullTri[i$6] = this$1._legalize(t + 2);
            hullTri[e] = t;
            hullSize++;

            var n$1 = hullNext[e];
            while (q = hullNext[n$1], orient(x$2, y$2, coords[2 * n$1], coords[2 * n$1 + 1], coords[2 * q], coords[2 * q + 1])) {
                t = this$1._addTriangle(n$1, i$6, q, hullTri[i$6], -1, hullTri[n$1]);
                hullTri[i$6] = this$1._legalize(t + 2);
                hullNext[n$1] = n$1;
                hullSize--;
                n$1 = q;
            }

            if (e === start) {
                while (q = hullPrev[e], orient(x$2, y$2, coords[2 * q], coords[2 * q + 1], coords[2 * e], coords[2 * e + 1])) {
                    t = this$1._addTriangle(q, i$6, e, -1, hullTri[e], hullTri[q]);
                    this$1._legalize(t + 2);
                    hullTri[q] = t;
                    hullNext[e] = e;
                    hullSize--;
                    e = q;
                }
            }

            this$1.hullStart = hullPrev[i$6] = e;
            hullNext[e] = hullPrev[n$1] = i$6;
            hullNext[i$6] = n$1;

            hullHash[this$1._hashKey(x$2, y$2)] = i$6;
            hullHash[this$1._hashKey(coords[2 * e], coords[2 * e + 1])] = e;
        }

        this.hull = new Uint32Array(hullSize);
        for (var i$7 = 0, e$1 = this.hullStart; i$7 < hullSize; i$7++) {
            this$1.hull[i$7] = e$1;
            e$1 = hullNext[e$1];
        }
        this.hullPrev = this.hullNext = this.hullTri = null;

        this.triangles = triangles.subarray(0, this.trianglesLen);
        this.halfedges = halfedges.subarray(0, this.trianglesLen);
    };

    Delaunator.from = function from (points, getX, getY) {
            if ( getX === void 0 ) getX = defaultGetX;
            if ( getY === void 0 ) getY = defaultGetY;

        var n = points.length;
        var coords = new Float64Array(n * 2);

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var p = points[i];
            coords[2 * i] = getX(p);
            coords[2 * i + 1] = getY(p);
        }

        return new Delaunator(coords);
    };

    Delaunator.prototype._hashKey = function _hashKey (x, y) {
        return Math.floor(pseudoAngle(x - this._cx, y - this._cy) * this._hashSize) % this._hashSize;
    };

    Delaunator.prototype._legalize = function _legalize (a) {
            var this$1 = this;

        var ref = this;
            var triangles = ref.triangles;
            var coords = ref.coords;
            var halfedges = ref.halfedges;

        var b = halfedges[a];

        var a0 = a - a % 3;
        var b0 = b - b % 3;

        var al = a0 + (a + 1) % 3;
        var ar = a0 + (a + 2) % 3;
        var bl = b0 + (b + 2) % 3;

        if (b === -1) { return ar; }

        var p0 = triangles[ar];
        var pr = triangles[a];
        var pl = triangles[al];
        var p1 = triangles[bl];

        var illegal = inCircle(
            coords[2 * p0], coords[2 * p0 + 1],
            coords[2 * pr], coords[2 * pr + 1],
            coords[2 * pl], coords[2 * pl + 1],
            coords[2 * p1], coords[2 * p1 + 1]);

        if (illegal) {
            triangles[a] = p1;
            triangles[b] = p0;

            var hbl = halfedges[bl];

            if (hbl === -1) {
                var e = this.hullStart;
                do {
                    if (this$1.hullTri[e] === bl) {
                        this$1.hullTri[e] = a;
                        break;
                    }
                    e = this$1.hullNext[e];
                } while (e !== this.hullStart);
            }
            this._link(a, hbl);
            this._link(b, halfedges[ar]);
            this._link(ar, bl);

            var br = b0 + (b + 1) % 3;

            this._legalize(a);
            return this._legalize(br);
        }

        return ar;
    };

    Delaunator.prototype._link = function _link (a, b) {
        this.halfedges[a] = b;
        if (b !== -1) { this.halfedges[b] = a; }
    };

    Delaunator.prototype._addTriangle = function _addTriangle (i0, i1, i2, a, b, c) {
        var t = this.trianglesLen;

        this.triangles[t] = i0;
        this.triangles[t + 1] = i1;
        this.triangles[t + 2] = i2;

        this._link(t, a);
        this._link(t + 1, b);
        this._link(t + 2, c);

        this.trianglesLen += 3;

        return t;
    };

    function pseudoAngle(dx, dy) {
        var p = dx / (Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy));
        return (dy > 0 ? 3 - p : 1 + p) / 4;
    }

    function dist(ax, ay, bx, by) {
        var dx = ax - bx;
        var dy = ay - by;
        return dx * dx + dy * dy;
    }

    function orient(px, py, qx, qy, rx, ry) {
        return (qy - py) * (rx - qx) - (qx - px) * (ry - qy) < 0;
    }

    function inCircle(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, px, py) {
        var dx = ax - px;
        var dy = ay - py;
        var ex = bx - px;
        var ey = by - py;
        var fx = cx - px;
        var fy = cy - py;

        var ap = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        var bp = ex * ex + ey * ey;
        var cp = fx * fx + fy * fy;

        return dx * (ey * cp - bp * fy) -
               dy * (ex * cp - bp * fx) +
               ap * (ex * fy - ey * fx) < 0;
    }

    function circumradius(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy) {
        var dx = bx - ax;
        var dy = by - ay;
        var ex = cx - ax;
        var ey = cy - ay;

        var bl = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        var cl = ex * ex + ey * ey;
        var d = 0.5 / (dx * ey - dy * ex);

        var x = (ey * bl - dy * cl) * d;
        var y = (dx * cl - ex * bl) * d;

        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    function circumcenter(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy) {
        var dx = bx - ax;
        var dy = by - ay;
        var ex = cx - ax;
        var ey = cy - ay;

        var bl = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        var cl = ex * ex + ey * ey;
        var d = 0.5 / (dx * ey - dy * ex);

        var x = ax + (ey * bl - dy * cl) * d;
        var y = ay + (dx * cl - ex * bl) * d;

        return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    function quicksort(ids, dists, left, right) {
        if (right - left <= 20) {
            for (var i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
                var temp = ids[i];
                var tempDist = dists[temp];
                var j = i - 1;
                while (j >= left && dists[ids[j]] > tempDist) { ids[j + 1] = ids[j--]; }
                ids[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        } else {
            var median = (left + right) >> 1;
            var i$1 = left + 1;
            var j$1 = right;
            swap(ids, median, i$1);
            if (dists[ids[left]] > dists[ids[right]]) { swap(ids, left, right); }
            if (dists[ids[i$1]] > dists[ids[right]]) { swap(ids, i$1, right); }
            if (dists[ids[left]] > dists[ids[i$1]]) { swap(ids, left, i$1); }

            var temp$1 = ids[i$1];
            var tempDist$1 = dists[temp$1];
            while (true) {
                do { i$1++; } while (dists[ids[i$1]] < tempDist$1);
                do { j$1--; } while (dists[ids[j$1]] > tempDist$1);
                if (j$1 < i$1) { break; }
                swap(ids, i$1, j$1);
            }
            ids[left + 1] = ids[j$1];
            ids[j$1] = temp$1;

            if (right - i$1 + 1 >= j$1 - left) {
                quicksort(ids, dists, i$1, right);
                quicksort(ids, dists, left, j$1 - 1);
            } else {
                quicksort(ids, dists, left, j$1 - 1);
                quicksort(ids, dists, i$1, right);
            }
        }
    }

    function swap(arr, i, j) {
        var tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    function defaultGetX(p) {
        return p[0];
    }
    function defaultGetY(p) {
        return p[1];
    }

    return Delaunator;

})));
    
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, loader, terrain, glsl, uniforms, root, tree;
    
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = "";

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 51200);
camera.position.set(-3072, 2048, -3072);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

controls.minDistance = 8;
controls.maxDistance = 10240;
    
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
    
//simple pseudo quadtree
var points = [], indices = [], quad_uvs = [], groups = [], materials = [];
getSegmentSubpoints(0, new THREE.Vector3(-1024, 0, -1024), 1024, 1024, 4);
getSegmentSubpoints(1, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1024), 1024, 1024, 4);
getSegmentSubpoints(2, new THREE.Vector3(-1024, 0, 0), 1024, 1024, 4);
    
getSegmentSubpoints(3, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(4, new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, 0), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(5, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 512), 512, 512, 8);
getSegmentSubpoints(6, new THREE.Vector3(512, 0, 512), 512, 512, 8);
  
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
    
geometry.setIndex(indices);
    
geometry.setAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(quad_uvs), 2 ) );
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
var materials = [];
var colors = [new THREE.Color(0xe6194b), new THREE.Color(0x3cb44b), new THREE.Color(0xffe119), new THREE.Color(0x4363d8), new THREE.Color(0xf58231), new THREE.Color(0x911eb4), new THREE.Color(0x46f0f0) ]
groups.forEach(function(g_, i_){ geometry.addGroup(g_.start, g_.end, g_.id); materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true, color: colors[i_]})) });
      
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
plane.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, 0);
plane.position.set(-1152, 0, 0);
scene.add(plane);

//delaunay
materials = [];
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
var indexDelaunay = Delaunator.from(points.map(v => { return [v.x, v.z]; }) );
var meshIndex = [];
for (let i = 0; i < indexDelaunay.triangles.length; i++){ meshIndex.push(indexDelaunay.triangles[i]); }

geometry.setIndex(meshIndex);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
count = 0;
    
for(var i = 0; i < meshIndex.length; i += 6){
    
    geometry.addGroup(i, 6, i / 6);
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true, color: new THREE.Color("hsl(" + (360 / 316 * count) + ",80%, 80%)")}))
    count++;
    
}
    
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials); //new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF, side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: true}) );
plane.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, 0)
plane.position.set(1152, 0, 0); 
scene.add(plane);
   
animate();
      
function getSegmentSubpoints(id_, lt_, w_, h_, level_){
    
    var subpoints = [];
    var subindices = [];
    var subquad = [];
    var lastIndex = points.length;
    var lastIndex2 = indices.length;
    
    var step = {x: w_ / level_, z: h_ / level_ };
    var stepT = {x: 1.0 / level_, z: 1.0 / level_ };
    
    for(var z = 0; z <= level_; z++){
        for(var x = 0; x <= level_; x++){
            
            var dx = lt_.x + step.x * x;
            var dz = lt_.z + step.z * z;
            var dy = 0;
            
            subquad.push(...[stepT.x * x, stepT.z * z]);
            subpoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(dx, dy, dz));
        }
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < subpoints.length - level_ - 2; i++) {
        
        if(i % (level_ + 1) != (level_)){
        subindices.push(lastIndex + i, lastIndex + i + 1, lastIndex + i + level_ + 2, lastIndex + i + level_ + 2, lastIndex + i + level_ + 1, lastIndex + i);
        }
        
    }
   
    points.push(...subpoints);
    indices.push(...subindices);
    quad_uvs.push(...subquad);
    groups.push({id: id_, start: lastIndex2, end: subindices.length});
    materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true, map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("textures/" + id_ + ".jpg")}));
    
}
 
function animate(){
    
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GLSL Intersection</title>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.116.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    
    
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have run the mesh through delaunay if you plan to render them as separately again afterward? What do you expect to happen at the transition boundaries between quads where points that end up shared start with different vertex attributes (uvs in this case)?

Comment: I don't plan to render them separately afterwards. It would be just one single geometry, however I have to use multiple draw calls to cope with 60+ textures (1024x1024).

Comment: You haven't answered the question about transition boundaries -- what's supposed to happen at the transition between tiles? That changes the complexity quite a bit. And why run it through delaunay to retriangulate instead of putting all of the original quads into a single mesh? Is it to hide geometry seams?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, the delaunay eliminates cracks between tiles since they have different 'resolution' for elevations and, in addition to that, processed geometry looks nicer (smoother). I have already done post-processing code which sort triangles by centroids and partition boundaries. It works fine, however while I need fast and optimized code, I am trying to modify Delaunay.JS to incorporate this sorting avoiding extra loops. All you need is to double sort triangles-by their parent partition boundaries and from left>right and top>bottom for sorting inside their hosted tile.

Comment: https://victorbush.com/2015/01/tessellated-terrain/ [Non-uniform Patch Terrain, Figure 7]

Comment: You still haven't addressed what's supposed to happen with the vertex attributes at tile transition boundaries. If different tiles share vertices then things like UVs will be interpolated at the transition between tiles which is likely not what you want. I would not use delaunay to do this and instead generate the higher level parent tiles with more vertices at the edge to align with the more detailed siblings in the first place.

Comment: So, basically, yes, I did my own algorithm instead of using Delaunator.JS. I will add it here as soon as possible.